# Devilbox - error, "No Host DNS record found. " even after adding folder name in /etc/hosts/

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system

I am using Devilbox and have been learning through documentation on how to work with it, I have created a folder inside /data/www/ inside devilbox folder and before that I have excluded the mention of "htdocs" from .env file.

Now when I made the changes by adding :

127.0.0.1 hi.local

inside /etc/hosts by using sudo nano, I am still seeing the same error "No host DNS found". I dont know what I am missing out.

Comment: What does your /etc/nsswitch.conf look like, particularly any entries related to DNS?

Comment: I just looked at it, and I am just pasting the doc in here:  [nsswitch.conf](https://pastebin.com/XmvEtxmm)
I don't know what I should be looking for.

Comment: It looks fine. I don't know enough about how devilbox works to help more. You might need something like `dnsmasq`, but I'm out of my depth here

Comment: The devilbox community isn't helping much either..